Feeds do not seem to post updates in chat
The last feed activity in The Meta Room on Stack Overflow is from 2024-06-14. The bot has not posted about new questions in the room since then, even though there have been at least 13 more. Some from the same day as the last post.
This affects https://chat.stackoverflow.com it does not affect https://chat.stackexchange.com and I am not clear if it does or does not affect https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/ Likely it does, since there are few other recent chat bugs seem to affect chat.SO and chat.MSE.
Other recent issues that might be related:

Chat search does not bring up new results
You Shall Stay Here Forever! (aka chat auto leave isn't working anymore)
No pong for the ping! No inbox notifications for chat pings


Its almost like even things that work break down when you don't maintainin it for years

It's like a car that drives a lot but doesn't get any repairs or maintenance for long years: at some point it just starts to fall apart and break. Engine might still work, but everything around it doesn't.

@ShadowWizard While there are problems like that, this recent set of problems aren't that type of issue (and were very unlikely to be that type of issue even before we knew what the issue was from the answer below).


It's not DNS
There's no way it's DNS
It was DNS

A few weeks ago we moved chat behind Cloudflare. For reasons that I personally do not understand (and SREs are also puzzled by), it took until now for our internal routing to chat.meta and chat.stackoverflow to break. This means the Scheduler service that executes scheduled routes couldn't actually reach the chat servers, so nothing that happens on a timer (such as leaving a chatroom or checking feeds) was happening.
The routing issue has been fixed, so things should be back to normal going forward.

Won't CF's Great Firewall put any new issues, e.g. if chat traffic will increase? Anyway, thanks! :)
